# Phonegap and C# web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, phonegap

a while back i made a C# Windows Forms which generates PDF report by using itextsharp.

Also, I made phonegap app that communicate with SQL Server that can DELETE, UPDATE and SELECT from database and it's working fine.

Now here is my question
How can I send data from Phonegap application to C# windows form, which run on the server side, to generate A PDF report?

This is what I found out so far and i'm not sure if i am going in the right direction
1.Re-write the code of C# Windows form to asp.net form
2.make a C# webservice which can receive data from phonegap and use asp.net to generate a PDF Report.
3.webservice should be at server side running 24/7

All I want is that "something" should be at the server side waiting for data, once it receives data it should make a pdf report out of it.

Thank you and I hope that was not confusing.
I just need to be pointed at the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer i was looking for.

These are the main points I mentioned on my question:

1. I made C# Desktop app for generating PDF report using iTextsharp
2. I want a Phonegap app to generate PDF report by sending data to C# desktop application.

The answer simply is to make **C# web service** and consume this web service from phonegap. it took me some time but it's working perfectly.